# Drupal 6 'View' Relationship query

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am new to Drupal.

I Have two content types 
a> Author
b> Story

Author content type has Author Image And Author Name. On other hand Story has Taxonomy Term Author.

Is there any way to Show latest story containing the Author image using view?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationship in view just like JOIN in sql Query.

Following is the video URL : answer to above question

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug0KhtWduRg